# Trying to display a random generated string on my page

Tags: php, string, sequence

I'm trying to display a random generated string on my page (php), but I have absolutely no idea how to do this.

I only want the following letters and digits to be used:

> B C D F G H J K M P Q R T V W X Y Z     2 3 4 6 7 8 9

In the following format:

XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX

Can anyone help me out, and give me a script which I can put on my page? Help would be really appreciated!

I tried this but it's not even displaying on my page for some odd reason.

```
$tokens = 'BCDFGHJKMPQRTVWXYZ2346789';

$serial = '';

for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    for ($j = 0; $j < 5; $j++) {
        $serial .= $tokens[rand(0, 35)];
    }

    if ($i < 3) {
        $serial .= '-';
    }
}

echo $serial;
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a place to get coders to do work for you.

Comment: @hargobind I was just asking for help because I just couldn't figure it out myself. I tried a code but it was not working how I wanted it to work.

Comment: Please update your question with the code that you've tried, or some possible approaches you may have found when searching for a solution.

Comment: @user3583175 Then try to figure out _why_ it didn't work how you wanted it to. If you run into problems and you can't solve them on your own through research and trying yourself, then asking a question here might be appropriate. Just asking for code is not at all what this site is about.

Comment: put each letter in an array with numeric index; then create a random number, get the number use the array element as the random character you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there. Here's a few fixes to your code;

```
<?php
$tokens = 'BCDFGHJKMPQRTVWXYZ2346789';

$serial = '';

for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    for ($j = 0; $j < 5; $j++) {
        $serial .= $tokens[rand(0, strlen($tokens) - 1)];
    }

    if ($i < 4) {
        $serial .= '-';
    }
}

echo $serial;
?>
```

I can't say for sure why your page isn't showing, but in your original code you were missing `<?php` at the top of the page.

**Edit**: Here's a quick explanation of some of the changes I made to your code.

1. Your code had `rand(0, 35)`. But since you may change the characters in `$tokens` in the future, it's better to simply calculate the length of the $tokens using `strlen($tokens) - 1` (the `-1` being important because `strlen()` starts counting at 1, whereas `$tokens[INDEX]` starts counting at 0).
2. Your code had `if ($i < 3)`, but you actually want four dashes, so I changed it to `if ($i < 4)`.

Comment: Lol. Don't know why I forgot that. Looks like it wasn't the code which wasn't working but just my stupidity. Anyways thanks to this question on SO I know that there are tons of other ways to do what I was looking for aswell!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $enters =  explode(' ', "B C D F G H J K M P Q R T V W X Y Z 2 3 4 6 7 8 9");
    $entry = rand(0,count($enters)-1);
    echo $enters[$entry];
    $output = "";
    for($i=1; $i++; $i<=25) {
        $entry = rand(0,count($enters)-1);
        $output  .= $enters[$entry] . ($i % 5 == 0 && $i < 25 ? '-' : '' );
    }
    echo $output;
?>
```

Comment: How would I go with placing this on my page? Sorry for the stupid question but when I put it in the php it's just not displaying.

Comment: The result is in the $output variable... Hust use it as you would use any string.

Comment: When I load the page there is nothing on it. @Rangad

Comment: You need to output it. echo/print or whatever you want.

Comment: btw. split is marked as deprecated, so it may not work on some configurations.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$charsPerGroup = 5;
$groups = 5;
$groupDelimiter = '-';

$tokens = explode(' ', 'B C D F G H J K M P Q R T V W X Y Z 2 3 4 6 7 8 9'); // from your question, format this however you want

$tokens = array_flip($tokens);

$resultArray = array();

for($i=0;$i<$groups;$i++) {
    $resultArray[] = join(array_rand($tokens, $charsPerGroup));
}

echo join($groupDelimiter, $resultArray);
```

Comment: Amazing. Your code is working exactly how I want it to work. How can I upvote your answer? I'm new to this.

Comment: Use the arrow left of the question. If your problem is solved also accept the answer. (The dotted symbol below the arrows)